# Editing the font size in accordion menu module in joomla 2.5

Tags: css, joomla, fonts

I'm using this accordion menu module in joomla 2.5 http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/accordion-menus/21961 , and the problem is that the submenu items have a bigger font than the menus in the starting level. I found in the template .css file where I can edit the size of the starting level menus, but not for the submenus. Here's a screenshot how it looks http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/1180/tikx.png
And here is the css code of this module:

```
    .accordion-menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    background: none;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.accordion-menu a:hover,
.accordion-menu a:visited,
.accordion-menu a:active,
.accordion-menu a:focus{
    background: none;
}

.accordion-menu  a img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    border: 0 none;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding:0 5px 0 0;
}

.accordion-menu li{
    cursor: pointer;
    background:none !important;
}

.accordion-menu .opened{
    border-bottom:none!important;
}
.accordion-menu li:last-child, .accordion-menu > li.last {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a!important;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}
.accordion-menu > li > .item-wrapper{
    height: 35px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
.accordion-menu > li > .item-wrapper a{
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.accordion-menu li .item-wrapper .menu-button{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 9px 5px 0px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion-menu li .item-wrapper .menu-link{
    width:81%;
}

.accordion-menu  li .ul-wrapper{
    display: none;
}

.accordion-menu  li ul li .item-wrapper{
    /* height: 30px;     */
    display:inline-block;
    width:97%;
}
.accordion-menu  li ul li .item-wrapper a{
line-height:35px;}

ul.accordion-menu li ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
margin-bottom:-1px;
 }
 ul.accordion-menu li ul li .item-wrapper{
 margin:0px;
 padding-left:12px!important;
 }
  ul.accordion-menu li ul li li{
 margin:0px;
 padding-left:0px!important;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you want to change is this:

```
.accordion-menu  li ul li .item-wrapper a {
    line-height:35px;
    font-size: 12px; /* Add this in */
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you, it works now.. How can i decrease the line spacing also?

Comment: You can also do this in the same bit of code above in my answer. Change the `line-height` value. If this answered your questions, please accept the answer by clicking the "tick" icon

Comment: Thank you, it's how I imagined :D